# How to Decrypt a ciphersaber hexadecimal text in pure C#

Tags: c#, encryption

I am trying to decrypt a ciphersaber encrypted hexadecimal message  using an IV mixing round of **20** with the key **MyKey**.

The messages is:

```
bad85d9e7f5aff959b6b332b44af2cc554d8a6eb
```

I am doing this in pure C# and it should return the message: Hola Mundo

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Hexadecimal text
        string hexText = "bad85d9e7f5aff959b6b332b44af2cc554d8a6eb";

        // Convert hexadecimal text to byte array
        byte[] encryptedData = new byte[hexText.Length / 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < encryptedData.Length; i++)
        {
            encryptedData[i] = Convert.ToByte(hexText.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
        }

        // IV length
        int ivLength = 1;

        // Key loop iterations
        int keyIterations = 20;

        // Encryption key
        string encryptionKey = "MyKey";

        // Convert encryption key to byte array
        byte[] keyData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptionKey);

        // Create an array to store the IV
        byte[] ivData = new byte[ivLength];

        // Copy the first `ivLength` bytes of the encrypted data to the IV array
        Array.Copy(encryptedData, 0, ivData, 0, ivLength);

        // Create an array to store the encrypted message
        byte[] messageData = new byte[encryptedData.Length - ivLength];

        // Copy the remaining bytes of the encrypted data to the message data array
        Array.Copy(encryptedData, ivLength, messageData, 0, messageData.Length);

        // Create an array to store the decrypted message
        byte[] decryptedData = new byte[messageData.Length];

        // Perform the decryption
        for (int i = 0; i < messageData.Length; i++)
        {
            decryptedData[i] = (byte)(messageData[i] ^ keyData[i % keyData.Length]);
            for (int j = 0; j < keyIterations; j++)
            {
                decryptedData[i] = (byte)(decryptedData[i] ^ ivData[j % ivData.Length]);
            }
        }

        // Convert the decrypted data to a string and print it
        string decryptedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedData);
        Console.WriteLine("Decrypted message: " + decryptedMessage);
    }
}
```

Now when I try it returns: `�$�#���Jf=�I���`

What mistake am I making in the code or am I implementing it wrong?

I tested the text with the following site to see if it was ok: https://ruletheweb.co.uk/cgi-bin/saber.cgi

Comment: If I recall correctly, cybersaber is based on RC4. RC4 morphs the key as it encrypts or decrypts. I'm not seeing your code doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*CipherSaber* uses as IV the first 10 bytes of the encrypted message. The rest is the actual ciphertext. The IV is appended to the key (giving the key setup input), which is used as input to the *CipherSaber* key setup, see [CipherSaber, Technical description, 1st section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CipherSaber#Technical_description).

In the posted code, an IV length of 1 is applied instead of 10, which incorrectly determines IV (and thus key setup input) and actual ciphertext. The correct determination of IV and actual ciphertext is:

```cs
private static (byte[], byte[]) SeparateIvCiphertext(byte[] ivCiphertext)
{
    int ivLen = 10;
    byte[] iv = new byte[ivLen];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(ivCiphertext, 0, iv, 0, iv.Length);

    byte[] ciphertext = new byte[ivCiphertext.Length - iv.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(ivCiphertext, iv.Length, ciphertext, 0, ciphertext.Length);

    return (iv, ciphertext);
}
```

and of the key setup input:

```cs
private static byte[] GetKeySetupInput(byte[] key, byte[] iv)
{
    byte[] keySetupInput = new byte[key.Length + iv.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(key, 0, keySetupInput, 0, key.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(iv, 0, keySetupInput, key.Length, iv.Length);

    return keySetupInput;
}
```

---

Furthermore, the decryption itself seems to be implemented incorrectly or at least incompletely. *CipherSaber* uses *RC4* as its encryption/decryption algorithm, which can be divided into a key setup and the actual encryption/decryption:

- The referenced website performs decryption using *CipherSaber-2*. Compared to the original *CipherSaber* (referred to as *CipherSaber-1*), a modified key setup is used in which the *CipherSaber-1/RC4* key setup is repeated multiple times, 20 times in the case of the posted data.
  A description of the *CipherSaber-1/RC4* key setup can be found [here, Key-scheduling algorithm (KSA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4#Key-scheduling_algorithm_(KSA)), a possible implementation for *CipherSaber-2* is:

  ```cs
  private static byte[] sBox = new byte[256];

  private static void KeySetup(byte[] input, int iterations)
  {
      for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
      {
          sBox[i] = (byte)i;
      }

      int j = 0;
      for (int cs2loop = 0; cs2loop < iterations; cs2loop++) // CipherSaber-2 modification
      {
          for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
          {
              j = (j + sBox[i] + input[i % input.Length]) % 256;
              Swap(ref sBox[i], ref sBox[j]);
          }
      }
  }

  private static void Swap(ref byte val1, ref byte val2)
  {
      if (val1 == val2) return;
      val1 = (byte)(val1 ^ val2); 
      val2 = (byte)(val2 ^ val1); 
      val1 = (byte)(val1 ^ val2);
  }
  ```

  The loop marked *CipherSaber-2 modification* in the code snippet is the modification compared to *CipherSaber-1/RC4*!
- The actual encryption/decryption is described [here, Pseudo-random generation algorithm (PRGA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4#Pseudo-random_generation_algorithm_(PRGA)), a possible implememtation is:

  ```cs
  private static byte[] Process(byte[] input)
  {
      int i = 0, j = 0;
      byte[] result = new byte[input.Length];

      for (int k = 0; k < input.Length; k++)
      {
          i = (i + 1) % 256;
          j = (j + sBox[i]) % 256;
          Swap(ref sBox[i], ref sBox[j]);
          result[k] = (byte)(sBox[(sBox[i] + sBox[j]) % 256] ^ input[k]);
      }
      return result;
  }
  ```

  Note that this algorithm is used for both encryption and decryption.

---

With this, the posted encrypted message can be decrypted as follows:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;

...

byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MyKey");
byte[] encryptedData = Convert.FromHexString("bad85d9e7f5aff959b6b332b44af2cc554d8a6eb");
(byte[] iv, byte[] ciphertext) = SeparateIvCiphertext(encryptedData);
byte[] keySetupInput = GetKeySetupInput(key, iv);

int iterations = 20;
KeySetup(keySetupInput, iterations);
byte[] plaintext = Process(ciphertext);

Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plaintext)); // Hola Mundo
```

which gives *Hola Mundo* as plaintext.

Comment: Thx, the code work fine and i understand my error now